# Why has getHttpSocketFactory been deprecated and what replaces it?

Tags: android, security, ssl

In Marshmallow, android.net.SSLCertificateSocketFactory.getHttpSocketFactory has been deprecated, with no explanation of why or what replaces it. As a security engineer, I don't get to work every day with Android but I've got developers asking me why and how... Does anyone have additional info? I've used up my Google foo, to no avail.

Note this may be related to 33352067--the answer to that may aid in the answer to this, but it hasn't been answered yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not an expert on this stuff, but since the Apache library was deprecated, I've been using the [`HttpURLConnection`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) class (as suggested by Google) with great success. For secure connections, I use [`HttpsURLConnection`](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/HttpsURLConnection.html), which has methods such as [`getSSLSocketFactory()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/HttpsURLConnection.html#getSSLSocketFactory()) and [`getDefaultSSLSocketFactory`](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/HttpsURLConnection.html#getDefaultSSLSocketFactory()).

As for why we should use `HttpURLConnection`, all I know is that Google said in their Marshmallow release notes:

> This API is more efficient because it reduces network use through
>   transparent compression and response caching, and minimizes power
>   consumption.

Not sure if this is the info you were looking for, but hope it helps in some way.

Comment: Yah that's all I could find also. Thanks for confirming though.